# How to fill remaining space in row-col with Tailwind with React

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I use (App Router) Nextjs with Tailwind.

I have this `Layout`:

```
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en" data-theme="cupcake">
      <body id="app" className="flex flex-col">
        <Navbar />
        <div className="grow">
          {children}
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

and this `About` page

```
export default function About() {
  return (
    <div className="bg-base-200 h-full w-full py-12">
      </div>
  );
}
```

I expect this `About` page to fill all the remaining space from `Navbar` and `Footer`.
Both Navbar and Footer has constant height. I don't know what is missing.

I tried `"flex flex-1"` instead of `"grow"` for the `{children}` or removing that `div` and adding `"grow"` (also `"flex flex-1"`) directly to the parent `div` of the `About` component however did not work.

I am looking for a simple tailwind-based solution without custom CSS. I believe this should be easily doable within the flex functionality of tailwind (I hope)

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to stretch the page so that it takes all available height in the browser? In that case you can use `<body className="flex flex-col min-h-svh">` and `<div className="grow py-12">About</div>`

Answer (score 0):

I see. I'd recommend adding these styles to your global.css file (I assume you're using tailwind):

```css
.custom-grid {
  display: grid;
  /* first 40px is your constant header height, and second 40px is your footer height */
  grid-template-rows: 40px auto 40px;
  height: 100vh;
}

.navbar {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 1;
}

.content {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 2;
}

.footer {
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}
```

...and adding up appropriate classes to your elements/components.
Example:

```
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en" data-theme="cupcake">
      <body id="app" className="custom-grid">
        <div className="w-full bg-slate-600 navbar">navbar</div>
        <div className="content">{children}</div>
        <div className="w-full bg-slate-600 footer">Footer</div>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```